# How to tracker users of Google Data Studio dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a Google Data Studio dashboard. I want to track the User Names or email IDs to check who is actually using the dashboard and who are not using it. I have used Google Analytics for tracking. But it is showing all the details except the User Name or email address. To view the Google Data Studio, the user should be logged into Google, then only they will be able to view the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by design with out-of-the-box Data Studio dashboards. If you want to do this, you will need to build a custom solution with a Community Connector and use viewer's credentials based reports. That way, you will have access to user identity in your code and log it as required.